# How to consume an AJAX JSON response in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax, spring

An AngularJS app needs to retrieve a JSON object from a REST service called from a Spring Boot back end. How do I modify the code below so that the response can be parsed into the properties of the returned JSON object?

For example, I will want to extract the `firstname`, `lastname`, and other properties from the JSON object after it is returned.

Here is the AngularJS controller that calls the REST service:

```
angular.module('confirm', []).controller('confirm', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

     // set the default value
    $scope.confirmStatus = "blank";

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {

        var str1 = "/confirm-email?d=";
        var str2 = $routeParams.d;
        var res = str1.concat(str2);
        var fnm3 = "nothing";
        $http.post(res).then(function(response) {
            fnm3 = response.data.firstname;//this line halts the program
            //replacing with following line doesn't work.
            //$scope.weblead = response.data;
        });
        $scope.confirmStatus = "success";
        document.write(fnm3);
    });
});
```

And here is the Spring Boot method that delivers the JSON response:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/confirm-email", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody WebLead confirmEmail(HttpSession session, @RequestParam(value="d") String dval) {
    WebLead dummy = new WebLead();dummy.setFirstname("justAtest");
    try{
        System.out.println("The Server Heard The registration form Request!");
        System.out.println("dval is: "+dval);       
        String sid = session.getId();
        System.out.println("session id is: "+sid);
        try{
            List<WebLead> wleads = myrepo.findBySessionid(dval);
            if(wleads.size()>0){//replace with better handling later
                System.out.println("wleads.size is > 0 !");
                wleads.get(0).setEmailConfirmed("true");
                myrepo.save(wleads.get(0));
                return myrepo.findBySessionid(dval).get(0);
            }
            return dummy;
        } catch(Exception e){return dummy;}
    } catch(Exception e){return dummy;}
}
```

**NOTE:**  We know that the post was processed at the server, because the terminal logs starting with the SYSO in the `/confirm-email` handler are:

```
The Server Heard The registration form Request!
dval is: a1b2c3
session id is: E1F844262F254E9B0525504723DBA490
2016-01-07 12:11:49.773 DEBUG 7288 --- [nio-9000-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-01-07 12:11:49.774 DEBUG 7288 --- [nio-9000-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-07 12:11:49.774 DEBUG 7288 --- [nio-9000-exec-9] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-07 12:11:49.774 DEBUG 7288 --- [nio-9000-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2016-01-07 12:11:49.774 DEBUG 7288 --- [nio-9000-exec-9] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: what is the JSON returned from the web service?

Comment: @Dan I am not sure, because `console.log(response)` did not return anything.  The program freezes before the breakpoint at that line, but yet the terminal logs show that the server-side method was called.

Comment: (Pro-tip: meta-commentary does not generally sit well in questions here. Questions that do not have an accepted answer are regarded as not satisfactorily answered by default. If you wish to clarify a question, then by all means (a) add a clarification at _the end_ of your post, explaining the misunderstandings that may have arisen, (b) try not to suggest that readers have guessed or spammed - most people are just trying to be helpful, (c) refrain from voting commentary - it's not of interest to most readers, who do not even sign in).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse(jsonData)`. Here is an example that should get you there.

```
$http.post(res).then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = JSON.parse(response.data);
    fnm3 = $scope.data.firstname;
});
```

Also, when I am working with the REST service I have, I like to put console logs in the function when debugging and then I remove them before I finish. This gives you an easy way to see what the service gave you back.

```
$http.post(res).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: $http automatically converts the response to JSON. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Neither of your suggestions alters the terminal log shown in the **NOTE** at the end of my OP.  Also, adding a breakpoint in the FireFox debugger at the line `console.log(response);` does not result in anything because the program is apparrently locking up at some point between the server side SYSO and the client being able to parse the response.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i wouldn't recommend building your own strings with parameters when doing requests with angular. You can simply do something like this:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/confirm-email',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    params: {
        d: $routeParams.d
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    ...
});
```

Secondly if you put the content-type header like above to "application/json" and if the server supports it, then angular will JSON.parse your data automatically and simply return a javascript object to you as response.data.

And the third and last problem is that your content will never display the given data in your code, because the POST call is asynchronous, but document.write the content of the variable fnm3 immediately after firing the request.

You have two options to fix this:

1. (Fast, easy, but bad) do a second document.write WITHIN the callback of your post-request
2. (The correct way) Define your value on the angular-scope instead:

   $scope.fnm3 = response.data.firstname;

and define a corresponding template to do some angular two-way-binding magic with it, like:

```
Firstname: {{ fnm3 }}
```

Comment: Your second suggestion involves changing the server code.  I have given the server code in my OP.  Can you show how to change it in terms of specific syntax?  Also, please clarify, is your third suggestion to write `Firstname: {{ fnm3 }}` in the html view?

Comment: you can also try to set the content-type in the client, its just the question if the server supports it. but you can just try it out, i will change the code above accordinly.
the third suggestion means exactly that, yes. to put it in the corresponding html view and put the fnm3 variable on the $scope variable instead of just an anonymous var in your function

Comment: Changing the http post to your suggestion does result in the server method being called and returning the same SYSO shown in the **NOTE** at the end of my OP.  However, the program still freezes before anything can be returned.  The firefox debugger console does not print anything.  Firefox just freezes after the terminal shows the server side SYSO in my **NOTE** in the OP.  Here is what I changed using your code:  `$http({method: 'POST', url: '/confirm-email', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, params: {d: $routeParams.d}
}).then(function(response) {console.log(response);});`

Comment: It even freezes when I remote the `console.log(response)` as follows:  `then(function(response) {/*console.log(response);*/});`.  What else can I post to help isolate the solution?

Comment: I am pretty sure by now that the problem is solely on the server-side. The client code looks good like this and should be correct.
Unfortunately i can't help you with the server part since i'm not firm enough with the used technology though, sorry.

Comment: How can I see what is being returned by the server?  I mean what the client is receiving?  From the client's view?  The Firefox debugger shows that the program stops at the last document.write, which is **AFTER** the http.post method, but yet I cannot find the response object in the firefox debugger.  Simply finding the response object would help, and falls within the scope of a front end answer.

Comment: The line after the POST request is executed immediately. It doesn't wait for the server to even get the POST request. You can think of this like that:
- tell the browser to send a request to the server
- do the document.write
- sometime in the future (some ms delay) the server will get the request and crash.

what you can do is try the post request in an external tool to be sure that the client isn't part of the problem. for firefox you can google for the addon POSTMAN

Comment: A working example of a spring @responsebody entity that is consumed into AngularJS and decomposed into its properties would be most helpful.  I am googling for such, but sometimes another perspective results in a better example link.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of writing less code and more efficiency and in order to make reusability of calling services (since you call your services in multiple pages) use the following code :

```
App.service("metaService", function ($http,$cookies) {  

    this.CallService = function (verb, serviceName, Data) {

    var Url = BaseURL + serviceName;

    switch (verb) {

        case "get":
            {
                return $http({
                    method: verb,
                    url: Url
                    , headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                        'Accept': '*/*',
                    }
                });
                break;
            }
        case "post":
        case "put":
        case "delete":
            {
                return $http({
                    method: verb,
                    url: Url,
                    data: Data
                   , headers: {
                       'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                       'Accept': '*/*',
                   }
                });
                break;
            }
    }
}

});
```

then you can call callservice method like so

```
 var SearchData = metaService.CallService1(method, "meta/selectAll", searchedMeta);
          SearchData.success(function (data) {

    $scope.Title = data.Title
}
```

Comment: The OP specifies POST, and asks about a specific result from a POST.  Your posting here is a general comment that seems off topic, and that adds a lot more code than the OP.  Do you have any specific suggestions for resulting the problem in the OP?